# error loops, Gaussian elimination julia

Tags: system, linear-algebra, julia, gaussian

the code below solves a linear system using Gauss method. when I run again, the error occurs:

```
LoadError: InexactError()
while loading In[176], in expression starting on line 4

 in setindex! at array.jl:313
 [inlined code] from In[176]:13
 in anonymous at no file:12
```

Running more than 3 times the system is solved. what's up?

```
A = [4.1 -5 6.8;7.8 -8 -9;-17 4 1];
b = [1,2,3];
x = zeros(3);
m = 0;

al,ac = size(A)

for k= 1:(al-1)
    #println("valor de k ",k)
    for i = (k+1):al
        #println("valor de i ",i)
        m = A[i,k]/(A[k,k])
        A[i,k] = 0
        for j=(k+1):al
            #println("valor de j",j)
            A[i,j] = A[i,j] - m*A[k,j]
            b[i]= b[i] - m*b[k]
        end
    end
end
x[al] = b[al]/(A[al,al])
for k = (al-1):-1:1
    begin
        s = 0;
        for j = (k+1):al
            s = s+A[k,j]*x[j]
        end
        x[k]=(b[k]-s)/A[k,k]
    end
end
println(x)
```

Comment: i guess the output is not correct, the type of `b` should be `Array{Float64}`, use `b = Float64[1,2,3];` instead

Comment: Hi Gnimuc. Everything is OK. I put the numbers in float format (1.0,2.0,3.0) and it worked;). Thanks for the tip

Comment: You will want to put your code inside a function; it's much better style (showing explicitly what the inputs and outputs are, and is easy to reuse) and will get much better performance in julia.

Comment: Hi Bezason. I wrote in the form of function and it worked much better ;)

Answer (score 0):

The error is occurring mainly due to type mismatch between the variable and the value, consider the simple example,

```
julia> convert(Int64, 0.1)
ERROR: InexactError()
```

The InexactError() is thrown because it not possible to represent `0.1` as an integer.

```
julia>convert(Int64, 1.0)
1
```

As you can see the value `1.0` does not have problems being converted to Int64.  So in your case since the type for array `b` is `Array{Int64,1}` and it sure cant hold floating point variables in due process and hence the error.

Considering @jeff 's  inputs, it might be better to pakckthe code in a function,

```
julia>function f(A::Array{Float64,2}, b::Vector{Float64})
          x = zeros(3);
          m = 0.0;
          al,ac = size(A)
          for k= 1:(al-1)
              #println("valor de k ",k)
              for i = (k+1):al
                  #println("valor de i ",i)
                  m = A[i,k]/(A[k,k])
                  A[i,k] = 0
                  for j=(k+1):al
                      #println("valor de j",j)
                      A[i,j] = A[i,j] - m*A[k,j]
                      b[i]= b[i] - m*b[k]
                  end
              end
          end
          x[al] = b[al]/(A[al,al])
          for k = (al-1):-1:1
              begin
              s = 0;
              for j = (k+1):al
                  s = s+A[k,j]*x[j]
              end
              x[k]=(b[k]-s)/A[k,k]
          end
      end
      return x, A, b
  end
f (generic function with 1 method)

julia> A = [4.1 -5 6.8;7.8 -8 -9;-17 4 1];
julia> b = [1,2,3.0];
```

This should result in the following transformation of matrix `A` into a upper triangular form,

```
julia> A
3×3 Array{Float64,2}:
4.1  -5.0        6.8
0.0   1.5122   -21.9366
0.0   0.0     -213.523
```